# When does a MySQL temporary table get dropped when used with ASP.NET and IIS?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I'm making use of temporary tables while running reports from server-side code (and doing calculations within those reports), but when does the temporary table drop? Do I need to manually call DROP on it at any point or does it just drop when the SQL command finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped
> automatically when the session is closed.

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

So if you want to save space before you disconnect, you can drop the temporary tables

Comment: I read through that part and what I'm trying to understand is that when the MySQL .NET library goes through the motions of reaching out to the remote db, executing the command, and then disconnecting. Is that what constitutes a "session" in this context?

Comment: yes a session begins with the login and ends with logout or timeout

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.